# Sending a string message to an IRC channel with C#

Tags: c#, irc

So I'm trying to make a simple IRC bot using C#, I have successfully connected to the channel and can receive and send messages, the problem is messages I'm trying to send get cut after the first space. I've already read the [IRC Documentation](http://irchelp.org/irchelp/rfc/chapter4.html) an can't seem to find any reference or note specifying a certain format for message sending, so far this is how I'm doing it:

```
writer.WriteLine("PRIVMSG " + CHANNEL + " " + "Welcome back!");
                        writer.Flush();
```

Although the actual message comes from a variable, but either way it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use colon (:) before the message, for example, like this
(and it would be better to use string.Format):

```
writer.WriteLine(string.Format("PRIVMSG {0} :{1}", CHANNEL, "Welcome back!"));
writer.Flush();
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask why is it better to use string.Format?